# Black screen after login Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04

I have updated my kubuntu 14.10 to kubuntu 15.04. And now after boot, when I enter my password on welcome screen, I will get black screen. It's looks like screen powered off. No cursor, no change brightness. Nothing. And when I try switch to text consoles (Ctrl+Alt+F1) nothing happening.
If I doesn't login in welcome screen I can switch to text console.

Comment: Are you using any proprietary drivers like catalyst or nvidia? If so, have you tried removing them? Also, try making a new user and see if logging into it works.

Comment: My notebook have only intel graphics. No proprietary drivers i've installed. But on desktop, when I have proprietary NVIDIA drivers all fine!
With new user will try. Thank you!

Comment: I've had the same problem. I did new instalation and I've got the same.I repeated once again, but I didn't check my old /home folder to add during instalation by mistake.Now my kubuntu 15.04 works correktly. Probably old configuration in hidden files in /home folder make error.

Comment: It's interested. When you did new installation the first time did you set your old home directory?

Comment: @Максим Т: Do you see an empty task bar (which disapear) at the black screen ?

Comment: No. I see nothing. I think monitor is switched off after login screen. I did following actions: after boot, when showing welcome screen I switching to console (Ctrl+Alt+А1ююА2б doesn't matter). Login in console. Switch back to login screen, enter password and press login. During login process switch back to console screen. And after few seconds my monitor switched off.

Comment: I have the similar problem running Kubuntu on a VM. I increase the memory for the video in the vm configuration from Virtual Box and disable 3D acceleration. This resolve my problem for now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may have a solution, I've been trying to figure out what happened for a few days now.
Deleting *all* ~/.cache and ~/.config is not a great idea, as those could be needed but. . .

In ~/.cache, I have deleted **only** the files with a 14.04 boot DVD, but I have kept the folders:

```
activityswitcher_wallpaper_preview.kcache
event-sound-cache.tdb.093cbe7e51f0423cb8a1384115f450a1.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
icon-cache.kcache
ksycoca5
ksycoca5stamp
motd.legal-displayed (0 kb)
plasma-svgelements-air_v1.0
plasma-svgelements-breeze-dark_v0.9.7
plasma_theme_breeze-dark_v0.9.7.kcache
[...]
plasma_wallpaper_preview.kcache
```

After rebooting, the desktop was fine.

Comment: Thanx, will try.

Comment: But after some time it happened again. :(

Comment: you should verify if your graphic driver is good for your card

Answer (score 9):

This has troubled me for some time now. I noticed it happens when I put Kubuntu to sleep or shut it down with a dual monitor set-up and then trying to start it with the laptop screen only. Anyway, here's what I found - one particular folder is responsible for this mess. Deleting it fixes my problem.

Here's what to do. Once you get the black screen go to a tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and do the following:

```
 rm ~/.local/share/kscreen
 sudo killall sddm
```

Then enter your password and login. Everything should be ok. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanx, but unfortunately I have setup system from scratch. Now it's works. :)

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and this fixed it. Thanks

Comment: In my case I had to delete the entire /.local/share folder to have lasting changes

Answer (score 8):

I ended up having to rename ~/.kde, ~/.cache ~/.local and ~/.config.

```
mv ~/.kde ~/.kde.old
mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.old
mv ~/.local ~/.local.old
mv ~/.config ~/.config.old
shutdown -r now
```

Not sure exactly which one did the trick but I suspect it was .config.

Comment: Wow. How many directories. :) Thanx. Renaming .kde and .cache didn't help.

Comment: Didn't help. :( I think something with power management. After password entry monitor switching off...

Comment: This is pretty overkill. `.kde` and `.config` store a lot of useful stuff. FWIW, I solved my problem just by moving `.local`. Then it's pretty easy to check back through you old `.local/share/` to see if there's any data that you might want to migrate back (e.g. tomboy stores notes there).

Comment: This worked for when my Kubuntu 20.04 broke. But this reset many of my settings of course. After the first working reboot I moved back the .local.old and .config.old. So I'd recommend to other people do delete these bit by bit to limit the damage.

Answer (score 3):

I too had the same problem in the fresh install of kubuntu 15.04 64 bit.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> after the system has started
2. System will prompt to login give your login name and press enter
3. Enter the password

   ```
   mv ~/.kde ~/.kde.old
   mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.old
   shutdown -r now
   ```
4. If you can get your gui on next boot don't forget to change
   'start with empty session' in 'desktop session' in 'System Settings'

Comment: Thanx! I haven't thought about cache. Will try.

Comment: Didn't helped. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; the problem was I had two different versions of the nvidia drivers installed. Looks like the dist-upgrade automatically installed `nvidia-340`, so just run the command below then restart and you should be good.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-340*
```

Comment: As i mentioned I haven't nvidia adapter in my notebook. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After going through few blogs and forums I came across solution but it didn't work for me. It's worth trying following commands and see if it solves your problem.

```
mv ~/.kde ~/.kde.old
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: I've tried this. Doesn't work. :(

Comment: Create a new user and give a try. It worked for me.

Comment: I've tried. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me.

1. From the grub menu select "system settings" which will put you to
   the bios menu.
2. View boot order (no changes are required).
3. Save change and exit.

Boot after steps 1-3 prevents blank screen. I do not know how but it worked for me well.

Comment: Very interesting. :) Will try

Answer (score 0):

So I faced this issue after changing my user password, and was only able to solve this after changing it back to the old one via 'passwd' command.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Check if you have sufficient space in `/var`, `/`, `/home`. Insufficient space prevents xOrg server to start.

To get the system back, you can run `startx` in the terminal, which should give you some hints, as indicated by [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/29yl0u/black_screen_with_cursor_after_login_linux_mint/cipwp56/). This command starts the xOrg server. The proposed solution in the reddit thread with changing `~/.xinitrc` didn't work for me.

If `startx` did indeed get your system back, you could reboot, back into the terminal and look if the xserver isn't running by running `xset q` as [indicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965765/2306363). Since `echo $DISPLAY` didn't return anything for me, I found [these solutions](https://nowardev.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/startkde-display-is-not-set-or-cannot-connect-to-the-x-server/), as `startkde` didn't work either (`startkde` would start the kde session). Most importantly, `/var`, `/`, `/home` should have enough space (check disk usage with `df -h`).

These solutions finally proved to be worthy, as I simply had no space left. After cleaning up some files and rebooting, KDE did start as usual.