# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1" crashes plasma 5

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, docker, cgroup

Following the instructions found [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/) I modified my `/etc/default/grub` with this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

on a kubuntu 14.04 and a kubuntu 15.04 machines.
The reason was trying to limit RAM usage of a dockerized Chrome (see [here](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/)).

This caused a blank screen with only the cursor after logging in on the kubuntu 15.04 machine, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614447/black-screen-after-login-kubuntu-15-04). I tried purging the nVidia drivers but it didn't work.

The only solution was to remove the line, remove the ~/.kde folder and restart.

Why is that? Is it possible to limit a process resources? Does this approach really conflict with Plasma 5 for some reason or I am missing something?

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04 with that same grub setting it makes the screen top widget bar go blank ... I am still battling on this