# Blank Screen on startup - Kubuntu

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I restarted computer and everything was fine, I logged in but instead of seeing my desktop the screen is black and the only visible thing is the mouse cursor. I tried restarting multiple times but nothing helps. I've tried searching for other solutions, but the packages are either not installed (tty) or I can't select the boot options. I am currently writing this on my phone. I use Kubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the terminal up (F2 in Kubuntu) or use (Ctrl+Alt+F1) as it's different to Ubuntu.
 Then enter

```
rm ~/.local/share/kscreen
sudo killall sddm
```

This black screen is legendary so guggle it or switch to Ubuntu like I did.
Check this out [solution to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614447/black-screen-after-login-kubuntu-15-04)

Comment: Thanks! The killall command fixed it. I switched from Ubuntu to Kubuntu because I personally prefer KDE over GNOME

Comment: Good to hear! I wasn't criticising your choice of flavour. They are all there to be tasted.